# Understanding oscilloscope pattern

Tags: oscilloscope, electric-field

This is likely an obvious question for anyone with professional experience but I'm just a humble software engineer trying to fathom the mysteries of my oscilloscope...

I created a simple square wave using an ardunio, 20us on, 20us off. When I observe the wave with my scope, everything is as expected. When I bring a second wire in close proximity (but not physically touching) to the wire on which the square wave is generated and examine it on the scope, I observe that an electric field is generated on the wire which exhibits positive and negative polarities (the red line in the attached picture).

How can this be? If the square wave is only toggling a positive electric field on and off, how can the detected field on the second channel exhibit a negative polarity? I'm guessing that there's some sort of calibration or grounding effect required but I've grounded both probes...

[image]

Comment: It's not "negative polarity", per se. It's an in-phase signal, so the polarity is more or less the same. You just lose the common-mode component of the signal, so that the average is 0 instead of 6-ish volts.

Comment: What do you mean by "lose the common-mode component of the signal"?

Comment: you've got a capacitive divider, polarities are preserved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second trace is capacitively coupled to the square wave signal, so only shows the changes in the electric field, not the absolute value.

Look for information on "AC coupling" and "Coupling capacitor"

Comment: But if the two wires are capacitively coupled, shouldn't they exhibit inverse polarities?

Comment: @GearoidMurphy: no.  A capacitor attempt to maintain a constant voltage across itself, so if one side goes positive, the other side must also go positive.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question but I'm still struggling to understand what you're saying. If these wires are behaving like a capacitor cathode and anode, then shouldn't they exhibit inverse polarity?

Comment: The series cap Blocks DC , but it doesn't invert AC

Comment: A capacitor does not have an anode or cathode.  The capacitor attempts to maintain a constant DC voltage across its terminals.  For an AC or varying signal, the voltages on both terminals will rise and fall together, but will have different average values.